# Populate labels when selecting item in listbox

Tags: listbox, label, populate, selecteditem

I have a listbox that contains the first index of every line in a text file.
the indexes are seperated with a ','.
I would like to select an item in the listbox and have it populate the labels I have in place with the rest of the line from the text file.

```
private void listsup_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Supfile = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "data\\Suppliers.txt";
        StreamReader spl = new StreamReader(Supfile);
        string word = Convert.ToString(listsup.SelectedItem);
        List<string> values = new List<string>();
        foreach (string str in values)
        {
            if (str.Contains(word))
            {
                string[] tokens = str.Split(',');
                labelsupnm.Text = tokens[0];
                labelconpers.Text = tokens[1];
                labeldiscr1.Text = tokens[2];
                labeldiscr2.Text = tokens[3];
                labeldiscr3.Text = tokens[4];
                labeldiscr4.Text = tokens[5];
                labeldiscr5.Text = tokens[6];
            }
        }
    }
```

Problem is, I'm not getting anything to display in my labels, please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my code a little, added some code that I used to populate the listbox itself, and now it all works just fine.

```
private void listsup_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Supfile = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "data\\Suppliers.txt";
        try
        {
            StreamReader supFile;
            supFile = File.OpenText(Supfile);

            string lines;

            while (!supFile.EndOfStream)
            {
                lines = supFile.ReadLine();
                string[] tokens = lines.Split(',');
                string tr = listsup.SelectedItem.ToString();
                if (tr.Equals(tokens[0]))
                {
                    labelsupnm.Text = tokens[0];
                    labelconpers.Text = tokens[1];
                    labeldiscr1.Text = tokens[2];
                    labeldiscr2.Text = tokens[3];
                    labeldiscr3.Text = tokens[4];
                    labeldiscr4.Text = tokens[5];
                    labeldiscr5.Text = tokens[6];
                }

            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

    }
```